# Background Native image

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

Is a Idea, but I have to asking for that, any one know if is possibile setting a `UIImageView` fetching the original image one the device?

I will to create an app with the possibility to change background but only when user change a self springboard background HOME.

Exist a code method to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking if you can fetch the device's springboard/home screen wallpaper?

No, you cannot. There are no public methods for checking the device's wallpaper.

Comment: Yes I' will fetch a device's springboard/home background image

Comment: You can't do that officially - there are no exposed APIs.

Comment: Ad a possibility to use the same function to allow user get image from camera roll and calling the Home Screen funcion? like this typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, PLWallpaperMode) {
 PLWallpaperModeBoth,
 PLWallpaperModeHomeScreen,
 PLWallpaperModeLockScreen
};

Comment: There is no public API for setting the user's wallpaper, either. The best you can do is save to their Photo album, and prompt them to set their wallpaper in the device Settings.